# Error when using CVXPY: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'multiply'

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, cvxpy

I am trying to use CVXPY to solve an optimization problem. Here is the  code:

```
N = 10
threshold = 0.3
p = 1 - threshold
para_dim = 1000
para_mat = np.random.rand(para_dim, N) 
para_avg = np.expand_dims(np.mean(para_mat, axis=1), axis=1)
A = np.random.rand(N, N)

def dist(para_mat, para_avg):
    para_avr_arr = np.tile(para_avg, (1, N))
    para_tmp = para_avr_arr - para_mat
    con_dist = 0
    for i in range(N):
        con_dist += np.linalg.norm(para_tmp[:, i], 2)
    return con_dist/N

def aggregation(para_mat, B, N):
    para_mat_new = np.zeros((para_dim, N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(para_dim):
                para_mat_new[k, i] = (para_mat[k, j] - para_mat[k, i]) * B[i, j]
    return para_mat_new
B = cp.Variable((N, N))
B_col_sum = cp.sum(B, axis=0)
B_row_sum = cp.sum(B, axis=1)
para_mat_new = aggregation(para_mat, B, N)
obj = dist(para_mat_new, para_avg)
cons = []
for i in range(N):
    cons += [B_col_sum[i] == 1, B_row_sum[i] == 1]
cons += [B <= A, 0 <= B,  B<= 1]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), cons)
prob.solve(method='dccp')
```

And the error is

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'multiply'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-53cd92582735>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('participation.py', wdir='participation')
  File "plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "participation.py", line 57, in <module>
    para_mat_new = aggregation(para_mat, B, N)
  File participation.py", line 40, in aggregation
    para_mat_new[k, i] = (para_mat[k, j] - para_mat[k, i]) * B[i, j]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

It happens at this line:

```
para_mat_new[k, i] = (para_mat[k, j] - para_mat[k, i]) * B[i, j]
```

I think the problem lies in the multiplication between the cvxpy variable and the numpy scalar. But I have checked the website and didn't find any problem with it. I don't know how to solve this one. Really appreciate a lot for any help.

Comment: That line of code does not have a `float()` call.  Please post the **whole** error traceback message.

Comment: `para_mat_new` is a simple numpy array, not a cvxpy variable.  I don't think cvxpy can optimize that.  Have you printed `obj` to see what you got?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your reply. In the following code, I use the decision variable 'B' for the calculation of 'para_mat_new'. 'para_mat_new = aggregation(para_mat, B, N)' and 'obj = dist(para_mat_new, para_avg)'. Should I define one function instead to incorporate the decision variable?

Comment: @JohnGordon Hi John, thank you for your reply. I updated the whole error message in the post.

Comment: Yes, but numpy does not understand and cannot store cvxpy decision variables.  That's the root of the issue here.  You're multiplying a numpy array by a cvxpy array.  If you want to produce a cvxpy result, you need to do all your math with cvxpy.

Comment: @JohnGordon You're on the wrong track.  That message is indeed the START of the traceback.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi Tim, thank you again. I have combined these two function into one but it shows the same issue.  Actually the ' para_mat_new' is a function of decision variable. I don't know why it cannot be optimized by CVXPY

Comment: `para_mat_new` is NOT a "function of decision variable".  It is an ordinary numpy array, filled with numbers, not parameterized values.  numpy arrays cannot be turned into decision variables.  Have you tried the obvious by replacing `numpy.zeros` with `cp.Variable` when you create `para_mat_new`?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes I tried. But it shows 
TypeError: 'Variable' object does not support item assignment. I don't think it works.

Comment: Can't you express that nested loop as a matrix multiply?  That should work.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you so much Tim. It worked after matrix multiplication.